# GUI git mergetool for Mac/OSX with dark mode, 3 panels, and allows editing local/remote?

Tags: osx, git, diff, dark-theme, merge

I am currently use meld and it seems to have performance issues on Mac/OSX that I don't experience on linux. I've noticed a surprising number of meld alternatives are really poor quality and un-usable in random ways and am finding it exhausting to repeatedly try each program, configure them as a git tool, then find out they are missing what I consider extremely basic usability features.

| somewhere | criteria not met |
| --- | --- |
| Meld | performance issues |
| Beyond Compare 3 | no dark mode |
| KDiff3 | no dark mode |
| p4merge | dark mode exists but does not work |
| Sublime Merge | can't edit local/remote panes |
| Kaleidoscope | can't edit local/remote panes |

I need dark mode for medical reasons. It is a hard requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond Compare 4 has [color schemes](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_morecolors) you can import or change, at least for the text (no idea if one can change the color of the toolbar/menu bar, for example.

Visual Studio has a tool vsdiffmerge that can be used as a mergetool, and of course, since afaik this is actually just a visual studio instance, [changing the color palette](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-personalize-the-ide?view=vs-2022) works here too.